# Why is width of view incorrect? SKScene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene

My score label sprite node x position is set to `size.width * 0.4` and it looks like this:

(The 'Time' sprite node on the right simply adds 100 to the score sprite node x position)

[image]

If I change the score label sprite node x position to `size.width * 0.3` it looks like this:

[image]

Of course it seems size.width is returning larger than the actual screen size. Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the viewDidLoad:

```
self.size = view.bounds.size
```

Answer (score 0):

The visible part of the scene corresponds to the scene's `view`. The scene is 1024 wide, centered in the view. This is why most examples start by centering things in the view — that's the visible part. If you need to convert between coordinate systems, use the `convertPointFromView` and `convertPointToView` methods.